# Single user mode gets hang at "random crng it done" in CentOS7

Tags: linux, centos, redhat, centos7

my root password got locked and i am trying to boot into single user mode but it gets stuck at below step 1.mounting v5 file system 
2.ending clean mount 
3.random crng it done - hangs at this step forever and doesn't boot but in normal mode it boots perfectly

Its not going to emergency and rescue mode as well due to root password lock .

please help me how can i avoid this "random crng it done" and boot into the single user mode.

attached screen shot [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VxCZN.jpg)